# The canonical divisor of the k-gonal locus

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Hi everyone,

I was wondering if anyone knows what the canonical divisor of the locus of $k$-gonal curves
$$ \overline{\mathcal{M}}^1_{g,k}=\overline{\lbrace C \in \mathcal{M}_g \ \vert \ C\ \text{ has a } g^1_k \rbrace} \subset \overline{\mathcal{M}}_g $$
is, when $k < \frac{g+2}{2}$, i.e. $\rho(g,1,k)<0$.

To make the question more precise, is there a formula in terms of certain divisor classes on $\overline{\mathcal{M}}^1_{g,k}$ that admit a modular interpretation?

Many thanks in advance.

Florian

Comment: The notation $\mathcal{M}_{g,k}$ is usually used for the moduli space of curves of genus $g$ with $k$ (ordered) marked points. I suggest to change it

Comment: Is the Neron-Severi group of the k-gonal locus known?

Comment: Not as far as I know. Also, I don't think that the Picard group is known. The Picard group of the space of admissible covers that is closely related to the k-gonal locus is conjectured to be generated by the classes of the boundary components. See the work of van der Geer and Kouvidakis in this direction: http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.3335.

Answer (score 5):

For $k=\frac{g+1}{2}$ the answer is in the paper by Harris and Mumford ["On the Kodaira dimension of the moduli space of curves"](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/ru/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN356556735_0067&DMDID=dmdlog8), Inventiones Mathematicae **67**.

They call the $k$-gonal locus $D_k$ and show that $$\textrm{Class of } \overline{D}_k=\frac{(2k-4)!}{k!(k-2)!} \bigg[ 6(k+1) \lambda - k \delta_0 - \sum_{\alpha=1}^{k-1} 3\alpha (2k-1- \alpha) \delta_{\alpha} \bigg],$$

$$K_{\overline{M}_g}=13 \lambda - 2 \delta_0-3 \delta_1 -2 \delta_2 - \ldots - 2 \delta_{[g/2]},$$

so one can compute $K_{\overline{D}_k}$ by adjunction.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, I am mainly interested in $k$-gonal loci of higher codimension : I want to consider this for a fixed small $k$ and all values of $g$.